# Intermittent Connection Issue with EC2 t2.micro Instance on AW

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I'm encountering difficulties with an EC2 t2.micro instance on Amazon Web Services. Utilizing Ubuntu as the operating system, I'm experiencing problems. Whenever I attempt to install MySQL, the instance becomes unresponsive, and I lose connection until I stop and restart the machine.

I'm utilizing the VSCode SSL extension, I also attempt to run a Docker container or install software with apt, the instance becomes unresponsive and I need to restart it.

Am I doing something wrong? Is the t2.micro instance inadequate for these tasks?

Comment: Just out of curiosity, have you checked the CPU and memory parameters of a T2.micro instance? Did you check if these are in line with suggested parameters for a mysql server or a docker container?

Answer (score 1):

A `t2.micro` instance has **1GB of RAM and 1 vCPU**. I would recommend using a larger instance type when running a database. (Or, use an Amazon RDS database.)

Also, please note that the **T-family** uses [Burstable performance instances - Amazon Elastic Compute Cloud](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/burstable-performance-instances.html). This is ideal for 'bursty' workloads where there are occasional high bursts of compute with in-between periods of low CPU usage.

This is great for **Test systems** or systems that run **workloads in batches**, but not good for Production situations where there are consistent workloads. If the instance runs out of CPU Credits then the CPU will be limited to a lower speed.

Comment: A Database on a machine with 1GB, pretty sure that's the problem but great point about not using the burstable CPUs of the T-family for constant workloads.